# Wix Installer - create installer that always re-installs over tself

Tags: wix, installation, upgrade

I am trying to create an installer that doesn't "carry" any files but does set a registry key and create a small folder structure (if not present)

The script does use CopyFile to copy files from a network location to a folder on the c-drive.

The idea is to create an installer that can be re-run whenever the network files are updated so that they are brought local for the user.

The CopyFile code has a RemoveFile line just ahead of it (in same component) so the file should always be copied "fresh"

The folder structure and registry key don't really need to be repeated but won't matter if they are.

I am also not worried about an uninstall (nor what it does as this install is always needed) **but** I can't create install after install in the system so I do need to be upgrading somehow.

I have (currently got) these bits of script in my wxs file

http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>

```
<Product 
    Id='*'
            Name='Eclipse Template Installer' 
    UpgradeCode='$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)'
    Version='$(var.ProductVersion)' 
    Manufacturer='Article 10' 
    Language='1033'>

    <Package InstallerVersion='200' Compressed='yes'  Comments='Windows Installer Package' />
    <Media  Id='1'  Cabinet='product.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />

    <Upgrade Id="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
        <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED"/>
        <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="yes" 
            Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED"/>    
    </Upgrade>
```

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When I run the Installer for the first time, it works.  Files are copied and all good.

I then tweak one of my copied files to force a new date/time on it and re-run the installer. It pops up indicating it is gathering info but doesn't then replace the file with the older version so I think the installer has concluded it needn't do anything as the current "latest version" is already installed?

If I choose Repair in Programs and Features the file does get updated.

I tried setting the IncludeMaximum to a yes but that doesn't seem to help. Same result.

I have also tried the MajorUpgrade command instead of the InstallExecuteSequence but I get the same end result.  Maybe for different reasons but not really sure. Maybe not using it right.

Can anyone tell me how to force my installer to redo everything it originally did even if the version matches?

My client can't make new MSI files so updating the version and rebuilding isn't an option. They just want to update the network files (templates) and rerun the MSI to get the files local.

The first run of the MSI also configures their machine for the templates so it is all very simple, which is what they wanted.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: You can't re-run the same installer - it just goes into maintenance mode for the installed product, and doesn't really do much - it's not a repair, because the product is already installed. A repair really does restore files subject to replacement rules etc. From what I can tell, Windows Installer isn't a good fit to do what you're trying to do, unless fix the dates and repair is all you need, so write a program to fix the date then repair the installed product.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bad idea (I'm not sure what else this product/tool is supposed to do), but you could condition the MSI standard action "PublishProduct" to '0' so that it never runs. This way, your MSI will install and never register itself on the machine. You can continue to run your installer over and over, and it will never detect that an older version is installed.

This is, of course, not the 'correct' way to go about things, but it works.